# Convert EPSG:3857 Geodatabase to MVT EPSG:27700

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to convert a gdb file to vector tile using ogr2ogr. The documentation mentions that I need to use TILING_SCHEME to do this : https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mvt.html

What would be the TILING_SCHEME parameter for EPSG:27700? It seems using '-t_srs', 'EPSG:27700' is not enough as QGIS complains that the vector tiles are still EPSG:3587.

Comment: Tiling scheme is as documented in the MVT driver page just the CRS code (27700 for you), coordinates of the upper-left corner of the upper-left tile (0,0) in the CRS, and the dimension of the tile at zoom level 0. Coordinates and dimension can be what ever but Britain should naturally fit inside the 0 tile. But then you must also have a client that can deal with your custom tiling scheme. Why don't you just use the EPSG:3857 tiling scheme like everybody else?